# CSS Vertical timeline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a vertical timeline down the middle of a bootstrap page with circles representing each date along it.

The css I have so far is:

```
    .middleline {
       list-style: none;
       position: relative;
       padding: 20px 0px 20px;
    }

    .middleline:before{
       top: 0;
       bottom: 0;
       position: absolute;
       content: " ";
       width: 3px;
       background-color: #608dc5;
       left: 50%;
       margin-left: -1.5px;
    }

    .middleline li{
        position: absolute;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: #4f80bf;
        border-radius: 50px;
    }
```

I've been fiddling with this for hours now, but can't get it to center with the timeline circles (li) over it. The line with be to the left slightly with the circles to the right. Moving them with right/left just pushes them to the end of the page.

any ideas?

Fiddle of whole page: https://jsfiddle.net/vtb4t17h/

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle with the actual markup? (html+css)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vtb4t17h/

It's bootstrap so won't display in fiddle.
But the  vertical timeline  with (circles) is displaying.
Ignore the horizontal one at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like this: https://jsfiddle.net/vtb4t17h/1/

Basically change `.middleline li`

To look like this:

```
.middleline li {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #4f80bf;
    border-radius: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

I added:

```
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    list-style: none;
```

**What I done**

I offset the `left:50%` (which brings the li exactly centre), thing is they are 40px wide, so they need to be brought back in by 20px so get centre of that element, so `margin-left:-20px` does that

Comment: Yes exactly like that - thank you. 
What did the margin-left add to it?

Also, how would I make this go down the full length of the middle of the page with the text on each side?

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain.. remove the margin-left from fiddle and you'll see it go too far right.. "I offset the `left:50%` (which brings the li exactly centre), thing is they are 40px wide, so they need to be brought back in by 20px so get centre of that element, so `margin-left:-2px` does that"

Comment: no worries :) if this helped you please consider accepting my answer